# worst case- / best case keys for binary search?

Tags: java, time, complexity-theory, binary-search

can someone please help me with this question? How am i supposed to proof the keys mathematically?

Construct an arbitrary non-trivial array a that fulfills the pre-conditions for binary
search. Construct keys `ka`, `kb` with

```
a) worst case lookup time
b) best case lookup time
```

if used with binary search on a.

How many recursion steps does it take to find `ka`, `kb`?

Comment: ka = array[0]; kb = array[array.length >> 1];

Comment: läser du algodat? :P

Answer (score 0):

The worst case of BS is ²log N, as that is the maximu splitting possible.  The best case 1 (immediate match).

*Mind - I do not want to do your homework, but schematically:*

- As to a proof for the worst case: split as long as possible.
- Starting with n = N. Split into [0, N/2) with count N/2, [N/2 + 1, N) with count N - N/2  - 1 with might be 1 less: N/2 - 1 when N even.
- So for the worst case assume the first, longest, half.
- This consecutively halfs N, getting N / 2 / 2 / 2 ... till we reach 1; this is ²log N.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

My follow up question is:

at what index should the key be at to get the worst case run time?

for instance, the index of the key should be (array.lenth)/2 if you want the best case run time = 1.

Comment: As you start with `mid = N/2` and want that to immediately succeed for the best case, N/2. For the worst case the half that might be longest.